# Unable to access Children from json , react-redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, children

**Hi, I'm able to access the contact name Ron and use filter in it. But, I'm unable to access the children contact Alex and use it in filter. I have attached my output screenshot. I need to print children Alex also in it and use filter. Thank you in Advance**

```
        import React, {Component} from 'react';
        import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

        let arr = [{"id":1,
        "number":true,
        "location":"2",
        "time":11,
        "code":1001,
        "name":"Ron",
            "children":[{
                "id":141,
                "number":true,
                "location":1,
                "time":1504969439000,
                "code":null,
                "name":"Alex"}]}]

      const Tab = ({ value }) => <div> {value} </div>;

      class App extends React.Component {
                constructor() {
                    super();
                    this.state ={
                        search: ''
                    };
                }
                updateSearch(event){
                    this.setState({search: event.target.value.substr(0,20)})
                }


        render() {
            let filteredContacts = arr.filter((item)=>{
            return item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.search)!==-1;
            });

            return(<div> 
                <h1> Contact List </h1>
                <input type="text" 
                       value={this.state.search} 
                       placeholder="Search Here" 
                       onChange={this.updateSearch.bind(this)}  />
              <ul>
              {
                filteredContacts.map((obj, i) => 
                <Tab value={obj.name} key={i} />)
              }
             </ul>
             </div>
        );
      }
    }
    ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('container'));
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You filtering only goes through the first level of contacts in the array, so any contacts in `.children` will never be shown or be filtered against.

What you want to do is make an array that contains all the contacts, but have them at the same "bottom" level (`[{name: 'Ron'}, {name: 'Alex'}]`), so that we can filter on *that* array instead.

One way of doing this is to first `.map` over the original array and make sure we get both the "bottom" (parent) contact and the children in one array: (if the `...` syntax is new to you, [scroll to 'Spread in array literals' here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator))

```
const allContacts = originalContacts.map(parentContact => [parentContact, ...parentContact.children])
```

But that gets us an array of arrays: `[[{name: 'Ron'}, {name: 'Alex'}]]`, which is hard to work with. So we want to make a new array where we have concatenated all the arrays in the `allContacts` array, into just one. Luckily, there is a way to call the `.concat` method that takes arguments in an array. It looks a bit odd, but we can do: (more about [`.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply))

```
const allContactsFlattened = 
   Array.prototype.concat.apply([], allContacts);
```

So now we have what we wanted: a "flat" (one level) array of all the contacts. Your filter method already knows how to handle that, so no further changes has to be made.

To see it in action I included your code with the changes applied (in a slightly different way) + some comments:

```js
let originalContacts = [
 {"name":"Ron (parent)", "children":[{"name":"Alex (child)"}, {"name":"Emma (child)"}]},
  {"name":"Isa (parent)", "children":[{"name":"Sarah (child)"}, {"name":"Ahmad (child)"}]}
];

const Tab = ({ value }) => <div> {value} </div>;

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state ={
      search: ''
    };
  }
  updateSearch(event){
    this.setState({search: event.target.value.substr(0,20)})
  }


  render() {
   let contactsAndSubContacts = 
      // flatten the result
     Array.prototype.concat.apply(
        // transform from parent =>  [parent, child1, child2 etc..]
       [], originalContacts.map(contact => [contact, ...contact.children])
      );
    let filteredContacts = contactsAndSubContacts.filter((item)=>{
     // NOTE: you probably want to use toLowerCase()
      // on this.state.search as well
      return item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.search.toLowerCase())!==-1;
    });

    return(<div> 
        <h1> Contact List </h1>
        <input type="text" 
          value={this.state.search} 
          placeholder="Search Here" 
          onChange={this.updateSearch.bind(this)}  />
        <ul>
          {
            filteredContacts.map((obj, i) => 
                                 <Tab value={obj.name} key={i} />)
                                 }
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Wow,Thank you so much bro. Well Explained. :)